# How to switch to REPLACE mode in VIM

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I know I can do this by pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> in INSERT mode, but that requires some stretching. Is there any more convenient shortcut to go directly from NORMAL mode to REPLACE mode?

Comment: Also, on MacBook you cant enter REPLACE mode by pressing `Insert` in INSERT mode at all.

Comment: @crollywood's statement holds true on linux as well (at least on KDE Plasma 5)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

From the ViM manual:

```
5. Replace mode                         *Replace* *Replace-mode* *mode-replace*

Enter Replace mode with the "R" command in normal mode.
```

Of course you can map any key to `R`, for example by doing

```
:map <F5> R
```

Comment: To tack on to the accepted answer: If its a number you are trying to increment, `^`+`a` will increment the number and `^`+`x` will decrement it.

Comment: In my case, the upper case "R" is capital (`Shift` + `R`).

Answer (score 63):

You can press <kbd>R</kbd> and you'll get into the REPLACE mode.

Comment: Shift+R, actually. Pressing just `R` key (as you would do to type `r`) allows to replace just one letter and then goes back to NORMAL mode.

Comment: Possibly that's why he put R and not r.

Comment: There is no `r` key on my keyboard. When I use `R` it only replaces one character.

Comment: @SandRock Vim commands indicate shift by using upper case letters and unmodified keys with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 14):

`R` brings you into replace mode.

Answer (score 10):

You have to press R to go to replace mode. For this, you must first be in non-editing mode

Answer (score 6):

In normal mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

<kbd>r</kbd> will replace a single character.